# Have a time seperator : within a input field

Tags: php, html

Is it possible to have a  :  separator in a form input field for a manual time input? Something like the following example:

[image]

```
<p> 
<div class='field'>
  <label for='$time_in'>Time In</label>
<input type='text' name='time_in' id='time_in'
  size='10' maxlength='5' /></div>
</p>
```

Using "Internet explorer"

Comment: The only thing you could do is add a placeholder attr. ?! (with html)

Comment: That's what `<input type="time">` is for. Not sure about browser compatibility though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take 2 seperate fields like

```
<p> 
<div class='field'>
  <label for='$time_in'>Time In</label>
<input type='text' name='time_in1' id='time_in1'
  size='10' maxlength='2' />
:
<input type='text' name='time_in2' id='time_in2'
  size='10' maxlength='2' />

</div>
</p>
```

and handle them separately in the code, it will work!